# How to backfill downstream tasks in airflow

Tags: python, command-line-interface, airflow

I have an existing dag which is successful till today. After adding 4 tasks:

1. task A >> task B >> task C
2. task D

I want to backfill task A and it's downstream tasks. (in this case: only task A,B,C)

with cli command:
backfill dag_id -s 2019-07-01 -e 2019-07-07 -t taskA

Only task A was backfilled. There is no argument like '--downstream'. 
Can I backfill task A and it's downstream tasks with 1 command?

Answer (score -1):

As per [`Airflow` CLI docs](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill)

> **-t, --task_regex**
>
> The regex to filter specific task_ids to backfill (optional)

---

so i recon you ought to omit that `-t taskA` from your Airflow CLI command and backfill the entire DAG (instead of backfilling individual tasks)